# Makefile for Java cannot find package

Tags: java, makefile

Hello I am new in Java development. I tried to write a makefile which should be runnable in Linux:

```
JFLAGS = -g

JC = javac

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:

 $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java



Heap.class: FibonacciHeap.java \
    FileOperation.java \
    MinLeftistTree.java \
    RandomPermutation.java \
   Heap.java 
default: classes
classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
clean:

 $(RM) *.class
```

In my assumption, Heap.class should be dependent on all the other java file. Also, the main file should be in it as well.

However, I cannot get it run, it shows

```
    Heap.java:3: package heap.FibonacciHeap does not exist
```

and cannot find the other reference from other java file, such as

```
Heap.java:61: cannot find symbol symbol  : variable RandomPermutation location: class heap.Heap
       list = RandomPermutation.GetList(listnum[route]);
```

This program runs fine in eclipse. Do you have any suggestions?

I am new and I might commit some mistake....and I don't know much about compiler and make file. If you can point it out I will be grateful!

Comment: You probably want to look at Ant. It's usually used instead of `make` for compiling and packaging Java code.

Comment: Unfortunately..it is a class project and it needs to be finished with makefile command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you set CLASSPATH.  I don't care that it's a make file or Ant - javac.exe and java.exe expect the CLASSPATH to be set when they run.  Where's yours?

I believe you have to set CLASSPATH in the makefile, before you run javac.exe.

I'd forget about make (and Eclipse) for a moment.  Can you make this project compile and run in a command shell?  If you can't, I'd say that you should not be leaning on any tools to help you.

Reading [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) might be helpful.

Is make really a requirement for fulfilling this assignment?  How will the professor know that you used Eclipse or make or Ant or command shell to compile your .java to .class files?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer first. Do I need to include the set CLASSPATH in the make file or in my java source file? Do you have any other document reference which can help me?

Comment: @Seen - The CLASSPATH is a system environment variable that needs to be set before you run your program, or as you run you program with the `-cp` argument. Just type `java -help` in your terminal.

Comment: I will try to find a way to see if I can put the environmental variable of classpath into the make file. Thanks again for you update.